# Set Analysis comparing two fields

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I've linked a list of closing balances to a set of currency exchanges rates using the date of the balance and the MatchInterval of when the conversion rate was valid. I have multiple currencies in both fields so want to return when both currencies match and apply the correct exchange rate.

```
sum( {$ <BalanceAutoNumber={"=BalanceCurrency=Currency"}>} ClosingBalance*CADMultiply)
```

As per an online guide, I have added the field BalanceAutoNumber to the Balances table as my dimension on which to select on. However, I'm only getting results when there I manually select in both fields.

I can achieve this with an IF statement as below

```
sum(if(CompanyCurrency=Currency,ClosingBalance*CADMultiply,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an interim solution, I have amended my data model so that the interval match links between the data force this relationship.

```
CurrencyIntervalMatchRaw:
IntervalMatch(DateForCurrencyRates)
Load distinct StartDateTime, EndDateTime
Resident CurrencyRates;

join(CurrencyIntervalMatchRaw)
Load Distinct Currency
Resident CurrencyRates;


CurrencyIntervalMatch:
Load date(DateForCurrencyRates,'YYYYMMDD')&'_'&Currency as %Join_CurrencyRates,
    Currency,
    StartDateTime,
    EndDateTime
Resident CurrencyIntervalMatchRaw;

Drop Table CurrencyIntervalMatchRaw;
Drop Field DateForCurrencyRates From Balances;
```

With this revised model, I don't need set analysis to limit the data shown.